# Is there any API integration for gcash payment?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, payment-gateway

I'm using react-native for my app, it requires online payments. Since lots of people already using "gcash" to pay online, I'd like to ask if there is an API for that?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if GCash provides their own API but Paymongo has an API that can collect G-Cash payments. Perhaps you can check it out. Looks like they just charge per transaction.

Per https://developers.paymongo.com/docs/accepting-gcash-payments,
*Collecting GCash payments on your website starts with creating a resource to generate a checkout URL where your customer needs to authorize an amount, wait for the authorization to complete and create a Payment resource to receive the authorized amount.
A Source resource is used to generate GCash checkout URL to authorize a certain amount to be deducted from your customer's GCash account and send it to your PayMongo account. After completing the authorization, your integration uses the chargeable source to make a create payment request and receive the payment.*

Specific API endpoints are listed on https://developers.paymongo.com/reference.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29101885)

Comment: Thanks for the review! Edited my answer to provide substantial info.

Comment: This is a third-party commercial solution, not GCash per se.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using curl.
This [link](https://docs.adyen.com/payment-methods/gcash/api-only?tab=codeBlockapi_only_payments_1) may help you.

```
curl https://checkout-test.adyen.com/v66/payments \
-H "x-API-key: YOUR_X-API-KEY" \
-H "content-type: application/json" \
-d '{
  "merchantAccount":"YOUR_MERCHANT_ACCOUNT",
  "reference":"YOUR_ORDER_NUMBER",
  "amount":{
    "currency":"PHP",
    "value":1000
  },
  "paymentMethod":{
    "type":"gcash"
  },
  "returnUrl":"https://your-company.com/checkout?shopperOrder=12xy.."
}'
```

Comment: this is adyen API.. and unfortunately their service is not yet available here in the PH.

Comment: This is a third-party commercial solution, not GCash per se.

Answer (score 0):

#### Is there any API integration for GCASH payment?

**Yes**. There is an API for GCASH in which software developers can use for integration.

##### Is the API available for the general public use?

**No**. As of this time of writing, GCASH didn't seem to publish the developer docs. Only some selected entities can access these APIs and developer documentations.

#### Who have access to the GCASH API?

PayMongo, Maya, Adyen, and others have access to the GCASH API. They then have their own APIs that would allow others to access the GCASH API via their custom interfaces.

##### Examples

Based on my experience, here is what I've already tried:

- [GCash, Maya, and other e-wallets via **PayMongo**](https://developers.paymongo.com/docs/e-wallets)
- [GCash, Maya, and other payment methods via **Maya**](https://developers.maya.ph/docs/learn-how-to-integrate-maya-checkout) but [by default GCash is not immediately available, you would have to request for it](https://developers.maya.ph/discuss/62f107ddf191ff023e0f76bf).

Comment: Provide a link supporting your answer.

Comment: @JhourladEstrella I've added some extra links that might help. These PH FinTech solutions aren't that straightforward like PayPal. You might have to learn a lot of things the hard way.

Answer (score -1):

[Adyen PHP G-Cash](https://docs.adyen.com/payment-methods/gcash/api-only?tab=codeBlockapi_only_payments_KCs5x_PHP_4)

```
$client = new \Adyen\Client();
$client->setXApiKey("YOUR_X-API-KEY");
$service = new \Adyen\Service\Checkout($client);
 
$params = array(
  "amount" => array(
    "currency" => "PHP",
    "value" => 1000
  ),
  "reference" => "YOUR_ORDER_NUMBER",
  "paymentMethod" => array(
    "type" => "gcash"
  ),
  "returnUrl" => "https://your-company.com/checkout?shopperOrder=12xy..",
  "merchantAccount" => "YOUR_MERCHANT_ACCOUNT"
);
$result = $service->payments($params);
```

Comment: where can you get API key? as far as I know Gcash no longer provides API keys

Comment: This is a third-party commercial solution, not GCash per se.